# How to change application Sharing & Permissions using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, permission

If I right-click an application and click Get Info, a window like in the following image pops up:

[image: App Store Get Info]

Then, after unlocking the Sharing & Permissions section, let's say I wish to change the permissions for everyone to No Access.

This is fairly simple to do through the GUI, but I was wondering if it was possible to do this through Terminal.

I know I could simply use chmod and change the permissions recursively for the application directory like that, but I would prefer a solution that simply changes the permissions in the same way the GUI does such that it is updated accordingly in the Info window for the app.

**Edit:**

I do not believe this is a duplicate of [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371084/from-command-line-on-macos-how-to-add-a-user-group-to-the-sharing-and-permissio) because the answer to it only shows how to add access control entries, not how to modify them.

Comment: Removing ACL is used with the `-a` command which is now included in the selected answer of the duplicate. Perhaps you can show how you have an existing entry and can't figure out how to remove / add / change. Writing new permissions and ACL is additive so when you add a new permission it doesn't remove the other but unions them. Removal can also remove some / all of a list. I appreciate the edit, but am not sure this is distinct yet.

Comment: @bmike That is fair. I assume I would replace mygroup with everyone in my case then. My only additional question would be what the answer in the link provided meant by "and for a file:" Could you explain what was meant by that?